# Drupal Commerce: Add content nodes to checkout steps

Tags: commerce

We have a number of checkout steps that have some content in them that can only be edited via templates which is not ideal for clients.

Is it possible to create content nodes in the CMS that can then be used on the checkout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is! With the module [commerce_extra_panes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_panes) you can add nodes (content) to the checkout.

Comment: Cheers Lenni, that does the trick.